# How does the 'passwd' command gain root user permissions?

Tags: linux, security, permissions, root

How does Linux know that it has to give euid 0 (uid of root) to only certain process like passwd, setuid, etc.

If a process can gain root permissions, will it not lead to potential security breaches in the Linux platform?

For example, if I write a program that can can gain root user permissions like passwd, I may corrupt important system files like /etc/passwd, /etc/groups.

How does Linux manage to still be secure?

Comment: Flag this question and ask for moderator attention to migrate it to the other SE site.

Answer (score 17):

The `passwd` program has the *setuid* bit set, which you can see with `ls -l`:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 39104 2009-12-06 05:35 /usr/bin/passwd
```

It's the `s` (the fourth character of the line).

All programs that have this permission bit set run as the owner of that program. In this example, the user is `root` (third word of the line).

These setuid programs need to make sure that they don't damage anything, since every user of the system can run them with *effective root privileges*. That's why you can only change your own password. Linux and other similar operating systems are still secure because the authors of these setuid programs take a lot of care.

See for example [suexec.c](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/support/suexec.c?view=markup) from the Apache Web Server, which is a popular setuid program. There are unusually many comments in that source code.

Answer (score 5):

As an addendum to Roland Illig's answer, it's entirely possible to write a program that, when given root permissions, corrupts system files and/or compromises your system in various ways.

The problem is that just *writing* it doesn't mean it automatically gets to run as root -- it needs to have its owner set to root, and then the setuid bit that Roland refers to has to be set -- and only root has the right to do that.

In short: Yes, every binary with the setuid bit set is at least potentially a security risk. Exploiting a flaw in a setuid-enabled binary to gain root privileges is the most common source of so-called [Privilege Escalation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) attacks and they tend to be a big deal when they happen. Because of this, there are relatively few pieces of software that use setuid and the ones that exist tend to be under high scrutiny.