# permissions on /etc/shadow

Tags: files, permissions, shadow

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux and here are the details:

```
uname -a
3.10.0-327.22.2.e17.x86_64
```

When I check permissions on the shadow file I see the following:

```
ls -l /etc/shadow
----------. 1 root root 1467 /etc/shadow
```

I am surprised to see these permissions. I would think that 'passwd' would need at least read/write permissions for the owner to update this file. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 5):

That's normal.

`passwd` doesn't need read/write permissions as it's got the suid bit set, runs as root.

```
# ls -l /etc/shadow /usr/bin/passwd
---------- 1 root root   798 Jul 21 21:15 /etc/shadow
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 26688 Sep 10  2015 /usr/bin/passwd
#
```

More info at [Stackexchange "How does the 'passwd' command gain root user permissions?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101467/how-does-the-passwd-command-gain-root-user-permissions) if you want it.

Answer (score 4):

The permission bits usually don't apply to processes running with appropriate capabilities (e.g. when they're running with root privileges). A more accurate summary, courtesy of [Hauke Laging's post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117155/28235):

> Always assume that `root` (and any other user/process with `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` and `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`) can do **everything** unless an LSM (SELinux, AppArmor or similar) prevents him from doing that.

As [steve](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/104877/steve) already [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316794/28235), `passwd` and similar programs either have the suid bit set (so everyone can run them with root privileges) or are only meant to be used by root, so the permissions on `/etc/shadow` don't matter either way.